# Equation of hyperbola to look like the figure

Tags: calculus, geometry, systems-of-equations

The below picture is the figure I aim to model. I am using [Geogebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoGebra), which is an interactive mathematics software that I'm using to make the construction of the following hyperbolic figure in $3$D.

I tried making one by using the hyperbolic equation:
$$\frac {(x-k)^2}{a^2} - \frac {(y-h)^2}{b^2}= 1$$
I tried for different values of $a$ and $b$ but I wasn't able to model it.

Please help to produce such a figure. Thank you very much.

(I see this figure like half of a hyperbola which is being spun along the $x-axis$ and then rotated $90°$. While the open mouth comes out own its own I wasn't able to give it it's stretched out length in the bottom as below.)

[image: The hyperbolic figure]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: No one has any idea of your maths background. Without some work from you to show what you already understand, no one knows where to start. Expect little back if you show little effort yourself.

Comment: In $3$ dimensions, rotate $f(x) = 1/x \; (-1 \le x \le -0.2)$ about the $y$-axis. See also [Gabriel's horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_horn).

Comment: Also, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot+x+%3D+-1%2F%28sqrt%28y%5E2+%2B+z%5E2%29%29).

Comment: What is "to model figure"?

Comment: To find the equation for the particular figure manually such as using 3D transformation or any other efficient method

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum.

Comment: @Shriyakakar, the comment by BeKind to me seems pretty close to what you're asking (check the link BeKind has provided). The following equation $x = \frac {-1}{\surd {(y^2 + z^2)}}$ is used and it produces nearly the same figure as you have requested. Kindly engage with BeKind (or any other user in general) to get more clarification.

Comment: @Shriyakakar: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Can you provide a link to a description of the object pictured? Is it a famous landmark or sculpture? Where was the photo taken? A cursory Google image search doesn't seem to identify it, although there seem to be a few structures like it around the world.

Comment: Expanding on @Blue's comment, when you reproduce the work of others, it is proper academic practice to cite the source of that work.  To do otherwise is plagiarism.  Please edit your question to provide a citation for the source of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure in the image that you attached can be modelled by a one sheet hyperboloid whose equation is

$ \dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} - \dfrac{z^2}{c^2} = 1 $

Here the $z$ axis is pointing vertically up, while the $x$ and $y$ axes are horizontal.  Since the surface has circular symmetry, then we must have $a = b$

As an initial approximation, you can set $c = a $ as well, and this will give you

$ x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = a^2 \hspace{50pt}(*)$

when $z = 0$, we get the circle $x^2 + y^2 = a^2 $, so $a$ is the radius of the surface at its narrowest point (which is the ground level in the attached image).  Now, to stretch the surface along the $z$ axis by a factor of, say $S \gt 1$, then the image of $(x, y, z)$ will be $(x',y',z') = (x, y, S z )$, from which it follows that $(x, y, z) = (x', y', \dfrac{z'}{S} )$.   Substituting this into equation $(*)$, we get the equation of the new stretched hyperboloid:

$ x^2 + y^2 - \dfrac{z^2}{S^2} = a^2 $

For example, if you want to stretch the basic hyperboloid by a factor of $2$ along the $z$ axis, and suppose $a = 5 $, then the equation will be

$ x^2 + y^2 - \dfrac{z^2}{4} = 25 $

Finally you should limit $z$ to the range $[0, H]$ in the $3D$ plot that you make with the graphing software, where $H$ is the maximum height of the surface above the ground, which is a parameter that you choose.